# regex optional lookahead

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to match all of these:

1. `startabcend`
2. `startdef`
3. `blahstartghiend`
4. `blahstartjklendsomething`

and to return `abc`, `def`, `ghi` and `jkl` respectively.

I have this the following which works for case 1 and 3 but am having trouble making the lookahead optional.

```
(?<=start).*(?=end.*)
```

**Edit:**

Hmm. Bad example. In reality, the bit in the middle is not numeric, but is preceeded by a certain set of characters and optionally succeeded by it. I have updated the inputs and outputs as requested and added a 4th example in response to someones question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're able to use lookahead,

```
(?<=start).*?(?=(?:end|$))
```

[as suggested by stema below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7361087/148870) is probably the simplest way to get the entire pattern to match what you want.

Alternatively, if you're able to use capturing groups, you should just do that instead:

```
start(.*?)(?:end)?$
```

and then just get the value from the first capture group.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? Your first regex does not work as requested https://regex101.com/r/GZYUmS/1 (includes the 'end' in the match) and your second regex could be improved https://regex101.com/r/QEiDYk/1 (doesn't create as many useless groups). While the actual (almost) perfect answer is [down below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7361087/5913518) from @stema , although I don't understand the need for the nested groups as `(?<=start).*?(?=end|$)` works just fine (see it here on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QEiDYk/3)).

Answer (score 20):

Maybe like this:

```
(?<=start).*?(?=(?:end|$))
```

This will match till "start" and "end" or till the end of line, additionally the quantifier has to be non greedy (`.*?`)

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ul8u)

Extended the example on Regexr to not only work with digits.

Answer (score 4):

An optional lookahead doesn't make sense:

If it's optional then it's ok if it matches, but it's also ok if it doesn't match. And since a lookahead does not extend the match it has absolutely no effect.

So the syntax for an optional lookahead is the empty string.

Comment: I need to return the bit in the middle without the optional suffix.

Comment: So should you match `start456otherstuff`?

Comment: no, but it should match start456endotherstuff but only return 456.

Comment: @PaulHiles "I need to return the bit in the middle without the optional suffix" -- then don't capture the suffix -- which should be optional but not lookahead. If it's lookahead then it won't be consumed and the engine won't see what follows it.

Comment: P.S. If you require that what you're matching is followed by either some pattern or nothing at all, you can embed the optional pattern within a lookahead that includes `$` -- e.g., `s/(?<=start)(\d+)(?=(?:end)?$)//` strips the digits out and puts them in `$1`. There's not much use for this if matching rather than substituting, since you can just match stuff without capturing it.

Answer (score 3):

Lookahead alone won't do the job.  Try this:

```
(?<=start)(?:(?!end).)*
```

The lookbehind positions you after the word "start", then the rest of it consumes everything until (but not including) the next occurrence of "end".

Here's a **[demo on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/1sDAP)**

Answer (score 1):

if "end" is always going to be present, then use:
`(?<=start)(.*?)(?=end)` as you put in the OP. Since you say "make the lookahead optional", then just run up until there's "end" or the carriage return. `(?<=start)(.*?)(?=end|\n)`. If you don't care about capturing the "end" group, you can skip the lookahead and do `(?:start)?(.*?)(?:end)?` which will start after "start", if it's there and stop before "end", if it's there. You can also use more of those piped "or" patterns: `(?:start|^)` and `(?:end|\n)`.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need lookahead?

```
start(\d+)\w*
```

See it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/FnivQ8UeCZ)